# Difference between two ways of calculating real return

Tags: finance

I've just learned the following way of calculating the real return rate $R$ of an investment:

> $$R=\frac{P(1+N)-P(1+I)}{P(1+I)}$$

Where $P$ is the initial value invested, $N$ is the nominal interest rate and $I$ is the inflation rate.

However, I've seen an alternative formula for calculating the same thing, which is

> $$R=N-I$$

So my question is, which one gives a better result for the effective rate of return of an invesment and why? Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second expression is an approximation which works reasonably well for small inflation $I$ but badly for high $I$

Suppose the inflation rate is $I=300\%$ (i.e. prices this year are four times what they were a year ago) and nominal interest rates were $N=100\%$ (i.e. nominally your savings doubled in a year).  Then, in real terms after interest, your savings could buy half the stuff it previously could and the real interest rate was $\frac{N-I}{1+I}=-50\%$ while $N-I=-200\%$

Instead suppose the inflation rate is $I=3\%$ and nominal interest rates were $N=1\%$.  Then  the real interest rate was $\frac{N-I}{1+I}\approx-1.94\%$ while $N-I=-2\%$, fairly close

Answer (score 3):

First, it's better to cancel $P$ in your first definition. Then 
$$
R=\frac{N-I}{1+I}
$$
And the second expression is
$$
R=N-I
$$
Actually, it is the famous $\textit{Fisher Equation}$.

The difference that there is a $1+I$ on denominator. Of course they are different. But economists sometimes use both since they are approximately equal when $R$ and $I$ are small. If you look at the data, both real interest rate and inflation rate are just a little above 2%.

Instead of using your first definition, let's start from an alternative form
$$
1+N = (1+R)(1+I) = 1+R+I+R\cdot I
$$ 
When $R,I$ are both small, their product can be ignored. Say $2\%\times 2\%=0.0004$. Hence, you can say
$$
N= R+I \Leftrightarrow R= N-I
$$

Here is the Wikipedia Link.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_equation

Comment: So, I understand now that the first equation is the more accurate way of calculating the real return, and that the second one is just a good approximation when $R$ and $I$ are small. However, $N-I$ makes perfect intuitive sense to me, and I really can't see why we have to divide it by $1+I$ to get the actual rate of return. Could you provide some intuition on this? Thanks.

Comment: The most accurate way is to write the equation as $1+N=(1+R)(1+I)$, which, mathematically, gives you the first defnition. It implies that the norminal income $P(1+N)$ is inflated by $(1+I)$, so your real income is $P(1+N)/(1+I)$ and the real return rate is $(1+N)/(1+I)-1$. It's why there is always an $I$ on the denominator.

I'm not sure if it is the intuition you need. But for me, if I use the first definition, I prefer using the expression: $(1+N)/(1+I)-1$.